# What is the power input to the iPhone 7 and where is the spec page?

Tags: iphone, power

I have an option of chargers with different amp ratings ...

The voltage is 5V but what is the current?

For example ... 2.4A, 1.0A ...

More importantly were is the Apple site for the iPhone 7 where they would have specifications?

Comment: Why does that matter?  The phone will draw what it needs. USB charges go up to 3A.

Comment: For tech specs, see:  https://support.apple.com/en_US/specs

Comment: @Allan - if you aren't aware that, in the broadest terms, 'volts are pushed, but amps are pulled' then no amount of spec detail is going to help.

Comment: I’m aware @Tetsujin, I’ve written about it many times.  He had the correct voltage, but amps was in question.  Curious why this matters since the phone would draw the current it needed

Comment: @Allan - I didn't mean if **you** were aware of it; I'm in no doubt you would know that, of course - I meant if the **OP** isn't aware, which many people aren't.

Comment: Sorry...must have mis read that.

Comment: Phone was designed for specific current.  The iPhone power cable even has a chip in it.  I'm not sure why it has a chip or what it does.

Comment: If you understannd the difference between push and pull can you draw a basic circuit diagram of how this effect could be modeled using basic circuit elements?  For example we can omit the AC/DC conversion and just model the power as a constant voltage source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the tech specs at https://support.apple.com/en_US/specs/iphone. The site includes specs for iPhone 11 so you must go down the list to find iphone 7.

Comment: Nice link.  It does not have the info. I am looking for, but I'm guessing if it is not there, it is not available.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, iPhones are 1A, iPads are 2A.
So long as the voltage is correct, the amperage doesn't *really* matter.

- If you try to charge a 2A device with a 1A charger, it will charge more slowly.
- If you charge a 1A device with a 2A charger, you won't see any difference to a 1A charger.

Amperage is "pulled" by the device, not "pushed" by the charger.